# Crosstab to show count of rows per weekday for each group

Tags: sql, postgresql, crosstab

I have a database with a single table. The table includes a column called `threat_group`, and another called `post_date`. This query gives me a list of all posts for each `threat_group` per weekday:

```
SELECT
    distinct threat_group  AS "Group"
    ,extract('dow' from post_date) AS "Weekday"
    ,count(post_id) AS "Reports"

FROM
    ransomwatch_posts
WHERE 
    post_date BETWEEN '<start_date>' and '<end_date>'
group by 1,2
order by 2
```

Now, there are two issues from a usability/viewability perspective that I'm trying to solve for.

First, if there are no entries at all for a given `threat_group` on a given day, there will just be no result. For example, if the group `conti` does not have any posts on Sundays, there will not be any lines like this:

| threat_group | weekday | reports |
| --- | --- | --- |
| conti | 0 | 0 |

I would like to get `NULL` (preferably 0) for the sake of building out graphs or tables.

Second, I want this data consolidated, I think through use of `crosstab`, but I've never built a crosstab, so it looks like this:

| threat_group | Sun | Mon | Tues | Wed | Thu | Fri | Sat |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| conti | 0 | 2 | 4 | 1 | 12 | 0 | 0 |

Can someone provide some assistance here? The best attempt I've come up with was this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM crosstab(
$$
SELECT
    distinct threat_group  AS "Group"
    ,extract('dow' from post_date) AS "Weekday"
    ,count(post_id) AS "Reports"

FROM
    ransomwatch_posts
WHERE 
    post_date BETWEEN '2022-04-01' and '2022-06-30'
group by 1,2
order by 2
$$
) as ct("Group" TEXT, "0" numeric, "1" numeric, "2" numeric, "3" numeric, "4" numeric, "5" numeric, "6" numeric)
```

which fails with:

```
ERROR:  return and sql tuple descriptions are incompatible
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get `NULL` for missing values, you need the 2-parameter variant of `crosstab()`:

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM   crosstab(
$$
SELECT threat_group                      -- AS grp
     , extract('isodow' FROM post_date)  -- AS weekday
     , count(*)                          -- AS reports
FROM   ransomwatch_posts
WHERE  post_date BETWEEN '2022-04-01' and '2022-06-30'
GROUP  BY 1,2
ORDER  BY 1,2
$$
, 'VALUES (1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7)'
) AS ct(grp text, mon int, tue int, wed int, thu int, fri int, sat int, sun int)
```

See:

- [PostgreSQL Crosstab Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3002499/postgresql-crosstab-query/11751905#11751905)

And no `DISTINCT` here.

And `ORDER  BY 1,2`.

And I suggest 'isodow' instead of 'dow' to get 1 - 7 for Mon - Sun.

And the faster `count(*)` - unless the column `post_id` can be NULL (which seems unlikely).

To get `0` instead of `NULL` for missing values:

```sql
SELECT grp
     , COALESCE(mon, 0) AS mon
     , COALESCE(tue, 0) AS tue
     , COALESCE(wed, 0) AS wed
     , COALESCE(thu, 0) AS thu
     , COALESCE(fri, 0) AS fri
     , COALESCE(sat, 0) AS sat
     , COALESCE(sun, 0) AS sun
FROM  crosstab( ...
```